# Burning Blueray disk with growisofs stopped at 'WRITE@LBA=b02ea0h Error'

Tags: command-line, burning, blu-ray

I successfully burned several Blueray Disk with this command:

```
growisofs -allow-limited-size -Z /dev/sr0 -r -speed=4 -J -V "Backup 01" /home/default/Documents/Backup/
```

But when I tried to burn an BD50 dual layer, it stucked at 52.27% with this error:

```
52.21% done, estimate finish Sun Aug 14 23:01:53 2016
52.23% done, estimate finish Sun Aug 14 23:02:01 2016
52.25% done, estimate finish Sun Aug 14 23:02:04 2016
52.27% done, estimate finish Sun Aug 14 23:02:21 2016
:-[ WRITE@LBA=b02ea0h failed with SK=0h/ASC=00h/ACQ=02h]: Input/output error
:-( write failed: Input/output error
/dev/sr0: flushing cache
/dev/sr0: closing track
/dev/sr0: closing session
:-[ CLOSE SESSION failed with SK=5h/INVALID FIELD IN CDB]: Input/output error
/dev/sr0: reloading tray
```

How do I overcome this problem?

Comment: This does not replace `growisofs` but have you considered using the original `cdrtools` package from this PPA: https://launchpad.net/~brandonsnider/+archive/ubuntu/cdrtools ? I have usually had better results here than with the Debian fork....

Comment: Thanks Andrew, but how do I use cdrtools, is it standalone app or it is used by growisofs?

Comment: cdrtools from this PPA replaces the Debian fork cdrkit thus for your purposes giving growisofs  mkisofs instead of genoisoimage to create the iso image of your files. If this also fails then the finger is pointed at growisofs itself and then the next solution is to use cdrecord to burn an iso created manually with mkisofs... A process of elimination :)

Comment: Sorry for my noob question, but how should I use it?. Now I'm running this command from terminal:

     'growisofs -allow-limited-size -Z /dev/sr0 -r -speed=4 -J -V "Backup 01" /home/rootsandculture/Documents/Backup'

    I added the ppa but when run sudo apt-get install cdrtools gives me "no package found"

Comment: With the PPA in place simply run `sudo apt-get install cdda2wav cdrecord mkisofs` and then growisofs will use the new mkisofs...

Comment: No great response from the bounty :(. Using the 'real' mkisofs had no better result?

Comment: I've got to test it. I have no more BD50 for burning.. they are very expensive :(

Comment: OIC :). I have seen the following option used with growisofs when using BD burning: `-use-the-force-luke=spare:none` and this might be worth trying:  https://lists.debian.org/cdwrite/2015/03/msg00001.html

Comment: Do you think this command is related to Dual Layer BD? Cause  I burned sucesfully Single Layer BDs (25GB) with the current command I wrote at beginning.

Comment: I suspect that a combination of a modern cdrecord and modern mkisofs would work well with this type of disk, pity I have none to test out myself :(.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `growisofs -use-the-force-luke=spare:none -dvd-compat -overburn -Z /dev/sr0=/path/to/file.iso`

You may also have to include the -iso-level 3 switch according to `man genisoimage` 
With  level  3,  no  restrictions  (other than ISO-9660:1988) do apply

You may also have to include the -UDF switch which according to `man genisoimage`:

Include  UDF  filesystem  support  in  the  generated filesystem image.     UDF support is currently in alpha status  and  for  this  reason,  it is not possible to create UDF-only images.  UDF data structures are currently coupled to the  Joliet  structures,  so there  are  many pitfalls with the current implementation. There is no UID/GID support, there is  no  POSIX  permission  support, there  is  no  support  for  symlinks.  Note that UDF wastes the space from sector ~20 to sector 256 at the beginning of the disc in addition to the space needed for real UDF data structures.

However the -dvd-compat switch should do the trick here.

The -overburn parameter may not be necessary, but I cannot tell that for certain. The -dvd-compat parameter makes growisofs close track/session/disc to make it more compatible with some Blu-ray players that do not like multisession discs.

The poorly documented -use-the-force-luke=spare:none parameter appears to be the key parameter to solve the problem. It instructs growisofs to not pre-format the blank BD-R media. Pre-formatting the media instantly takes up 256MB of disc space for defect management.

Source: https://superuser.com/questions/462782/growisofs-warnings-when-writing-to-blu-ray-dual-layer-discs

Comment: `growisofs -use-the-force-luke=spare:none -iso-level 3 -UDF -Z /dev/sr0 -r -speed=4 -J -V "Backup 243" /home/rootsandculture/Documents/Backup\ 243/`

Comment: Well added `-iso-level 3 -UDF` and it works now!!

Comment: @rootsandculture Updated answer